# Error in running RMIC via Ant using wsejbdeploy taskdef

Tags: ant, websphere-6.1, ibm-rad

I get the following exception when trying to generate RMIC using Ant task.

```
[wsejbdeploy] Error generating RMI code: RMIC command failed on project: .... with message:
[wsejbdeploy] error: The IBM RMIC version 0x1500 does not match the IBM runtime version 0x1600.
```

Please let me know how to fix this.
I am trying this using the WebSphere 6.1 server that comes bundled with RAD7.5.

This works fine when we use IDE to generate the EAR, and fails only when we use our custom Ant build file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means that JAVA_HOME in your shell used to invoke Ant is different from the Java that was included with the embedded WebSphere Application Server.  Try using the WAS_HOME/bin/ws_ant script, or set JAVA_HOME to WAS_HOME/java/.

Comment: Thank you, when I tried to run with RAD's jvm it got resolved.

Comment: Thank you, when I tried to run with jre coming as part of RAD, it got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The error
Cannot run RMIC because it is not installed. Expected location of RMIC is the following: 
will some times confuse. enable the "Capture RMIC verbose output to the workspace .log file.
and see what the exact error your getting. This option will be available in properties > EJBDeployment.

In My case it throwing error due to huge number of jars in class path.It got resolved after shortening the class path jar location.